# New integer is equal to the difference of 2

Tags: java, integer

I'm coding something for a theoretical airport case study and I need help with one bit. I've got 2 different integers with names: `maxfuelCapacity` and `fuelCurrent`, and I need something that says ' fuel needed to pump is '.....' being the difference between the `maxfuelCapacity` of the plane and the current amount. There are no real values so far. How do I go about doing that?

```
public static int maxfuelCapacity;
public int fuelCurrent;
public String name;
Boolean parked;
public String[] Plane = {
    "BA103", "BA493", "BA209"
};

public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
}

public void setParked(Boolean o) {
    parked = o;
}

public int getInt(String Maxfuelcapacity) {
    return maxfuelCapacity;
}

public String getInt1 (String fuelCurrent) {
    return fuelCurrent;
}
```

Comment: You can create a method called `fuelNeeded` that returns `maxfuelCapacity-fuelCurrent`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yeah thats right. I need it to tell me how much I need to fill up. Real values are not being used just need the code for it

Comment: You can simply print it out:
System.out.println("Fuel needed to pump is" + (maxfuelCapacity - fuelCurrent));

Comment: ok thanks. I'm really new most things are flying over my head. I'm being forced to make a working program in 4 weeks without having used Java in my life

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question seems to boil down to "how do I do subtraction in Java" which doesn't show much research effort on your part. Research is considered a key part of writing a good question on stack overflow.

Comment: I understand you're under pressure to make something work. Unfortunately Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of useful Questions with Answers. When you post a Question users will evaluate if they think your post adds value to the repository. Personally I think you'll get more value for your time if you spend it on Oracle's [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) than posting here. You'll get an overview and general understanding that no Answer will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, your method would look like:

```
public int fuelNeeded(int fuelCurrent, int maxfuelCapacity) {
   if(fuelCurrent >= maxfuelCapacity) {
     System.out.println("The tank already has enough");
     return 0;
   }
   return maxfuelCapacity- fuelCurrent;
}
```

So you call this method in your main function that does the calculation.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `return maxFuelCapacity-fuelCurrent`? (assuming that the other parts of the program handle having more current fuel than it can store)

Comment: For this particular case, may be yes. but usually it is better to do the check rather than thinking into you are accepting correct data. don't you think?

Comment: My first point still stands, why are you accepting arguments if they're already in the class?

Comment: the code posted for the question seems POJO without a `main`. so the calculation is not being done here for sure.

Comment: would the code you've just done substitute the one already in the comments or change something from my source code

Comment: yes it does substitute, I just extracted the calculation to a separate method and added a check for the inputs. nothing more. I have edited the variable names to make it understandable

Comment: The code OP posted seems a bit off, it could either be an Airport class or a Plane class. In the case that it's a Airport class, I would do it your way, but if it's an Plane class, I think it would be best to not use parameters

Comment: The class and package are as follow:   package britishairways;

public class Plane {

Comment: I need you to explain the accepting arguments thing. So what would I substitute in the code or add to it ?

Comment: let's take *class Plane*. it should consist only private member variables and public *get/set* method to access the values of the variables. So, checking the fuel will be done in another class that assigns values to `Plane`, like an `Airport` class that manages all `Planes`. the `Airport` checks if a plane has enough fuel to fuel them in case they don't. so the above method will be applied on all the planes arriving to a particular airport

Comment: No idea, may be try to accept if this is valid answer and see what happens